# want my application activated( bring to front) when i open a specific application

Tags: c#

i want my application activated( bring to front) when i open a specific application. For example, i opened adobe Photoshop; then my application should come front. And for any other application, it should be minimized. My application is in c#. Do you guys have any idea ??? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Than to your Question:
you need to use the [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI call, if you want to set a Application to front from another application, or you just set the          `Topmost="True"` Property that is your application always Top.

**Edit:**
Than you crate a Timer that call get [Process by Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) and if you found for examle Photoshop just call the WINAPI call to your own program or call

`this.BringToFront();`

Comment: hi ajacian81, Thanks for the reply. if you set topmost=true, the application will be on top always, right? that is not what i want. i want it to be on top only when a specific application is opened(currently on top). Thank you

Comment: This is not ajacian81 this is Venson ;-). I will update the solution

Comment: oops sorry... you know am new in stackoverflow... statrting trouble :)

Comment: No problem ;-) you can see the posters name in the right lower corner of the Post

Comment: If you accept my answer as that what you want, please mark it as Accepted by check that green button on the left side of my post so that other people can see what the right answer is.